# How to generate sequence number in python?

Tags: json, mongodb, python-2.7

I am basically trying to create unique, sequence numbers as ID's for my JSON records and it goes to MongoDB.

I have hundreds of records in a collection and should have ID like 'ALERT-00000000001' etc.

I want this to be incremented and should be synchronized among multiple executions also. I'm a beginner to python.

So kindly guide me or explain the approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use standard object ids? They're unique and don't need any external state or synchronization (which means way more reliable uniqueness).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Could be plz elaborate more on how to use it. If you are telling about mongodb object id, I know that. I dont want that in my case. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with sequences is that you need to store its state ("what is the last generated number").

Good news is, you can store them in mongo!

```
db.sequences.find()
> { "_id": "alerts", "last_value": 234 }
```

Then you can use [`findAndModify`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) to generate a new value and return it **in the same operation** (no race conditions, safe and reliable).

One downside of this approach is that you exert more load on your database to satisfy this piece of business logic. Depending on your traffic, you might need more powerful hardware, compared to using built-in object ids.

Comment: You got my point exactly. It has to store its state. Is there a possibility to retrieve the state. I don't want to load my database with more requests for ID's.

Comment: Well, the state has to be _somewhere_. And be accessible by all your workers. And you want it persisted. So it must be a database (doesn't have to be the same database. Redis is a good alternative here)

Comment: So finally I convinced myself not to put in DB. Instead I'm storing that in a simple JSON document. Is it a bad practise to read the state from JSON file upon every execution and update it at the end?

Comment: @KavithaMadhavaraj: terrible. Not only prone to race conditions on a single machine (if you have any concurrency going on), also not usable from other machines.